# How do I prevent Google Talk from showing my status as "idle"?

Tags: chat, google-talk

when I use GTalk, my chat program shows as idle when I step away from the keyboard for more than a few minutes.

Back when I used AIM, I was able to turn that off.  Any ideas on how to do that when using GTalk?

Answer (score 3):

Use a client like Pidgin and change the time-out settings. But then with the Gtalk application you cannot do it.

Answer (score 0):

There is an addon called **gAlwaysIdle** that was able to control this, but their home page is missing. See if you find is somewhere.